# How to set database path relative to web-app with Spring Web & JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, h2, spring-jdbc

Spring Boot / Web / JPA zero configuration is good for simple cases, when default values are sufficient.

But what if I want to place database file into webapp folder? It is not current folder for JVM and hence, relative path like `jdbc:h2:file:./data/sample` won't work correctly.

Consider [simple get started project](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/). How to set database path for it?

**UPDATE**

More formally, I would like to store database file at something like

```
servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/database")
```

Comment: Is this a read-only database?

Comment: No, it is just non-memory.

Comment: the webapp folder is a source folder -- it doesn't exist on deployment. Where do you want the database? With your html files? Doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: Ok, let it be incorrect, but I want it :)

Comment: @EngineerDollery you can hide below WEB-INF if you wish :)

Comment: But you can't you see -- this is a spring-boot uber-jar which is never unpacked. You don't have a filesystem to store it on. Nothing is writable. Your db should go in the system or application temp, or be hosted on a server somewhere.

Comment: @EngineerDollery suppose I have filesystem

Comment: Dims, that's like supposing the moon were made of cheese mate. Spring-boot builds an uber-jar, and the web-inf directory is inside that. You can't write to it at runtime. If you have a filesystem its outside the jar somewhere and you address it like you would any other filesystem (either by a drive letter on windows or through a mount on most other systems, or simply through normal directory paths if it's the same filesystem the jar is held in). Besides, it's not a good idea, generally speaking, to put your database there -- in most applications it shouldn't even be on the same box.

Comment: Okay, sorry for mentionning boot. It was not among tags btw. Suppose I am making WAR file.

Comment: Exact same problem. The inside of the war isn't writable in the general case. You can't treat the application archive as writable.